# Excel VBA - Copy Method of Worksheet class Failed - Used to function fine

Tags: vba, excel

I have a time card workbook that in it you can create a new card from the previous weeks card. It's worked just find until recently. I currently have 26 sheets, no code has changed but it throws a run-time error and higlights,

```
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets.Count
```

Here's the whole module:

```
Sub create_timecard()

'copy sheet afterlast sheet

Dim timeCardNo As Integer
Dim user As String
Dim colCount As Integer
Dim topRow As Integer
Dim rightCol As Integer
Dim cardName As String
Dim timeCard As ListObject
Dim msgBoxResult As VbMsgBoxResult

Dim weekStart As String
Dim weekEnd As String

Dim curMonth As String
Dim endMonth As String

msgBoxResult = MsgBox("Would you like to keep the previous week's projects?", vbExclamation + vbYesNoCancel, "New Time Card")

If msgBoxResult = vbCancel Then

Exit Sub

End If

'Get current week
curMonth = MonthName(Month(Date), True)
weekStart = Day(Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 1)
weekEnd = Day(Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 7)

endMonth = MonthName(Month(Date - Weekday(Date, vbMonday) + 7), True)


ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets.Count



user = Application.UserName
Set timeCard = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)

timeCardNo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count - 2 'minus one to remove summary sheet from count
cardName = user & timeCardNo

ActiveSheet.Name = cardName

topRow = timeCard.HeaderRowRange.Row - 1
rightCol = timeCard.ListColumns.Count


Cells(topRow, rightCol).Value = cardName
Cells(topRow, timeCard.ListColumns("Monday").Index).Value = curMonth & " " & weekStart & " - " & endMonth & " " & weekEnd



If msgBoxResult = vbNo Then

Range(timeCard.DataBodyRange(1, 1), timeCard.DataBodyRange(timeCard.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, timeCard.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count - 1)).ClearContents

ElseIf msgBoxResult = vbYes Then

Range(timeCard.DataBodyRange(1, timeCard.ListColumns("Monday").Index), timeCard.DataBodyRange(timeCard.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, timeCard.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count - 1)).ClearContents

End If

End Sub
```

I've searched one the site here, and I can't seems to get anything to work, other employees who are running the same sheet are not having the issue. I'm running Office 2013. and I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but it's the only difference, I have a Personal.xlsb for global macros.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code should have never worked, the argument is expecting a sheet object - so it should be:

```
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. I was getting another error that I was attempting to resolve and I must have retyped this section incorrectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries, don't forget to mark as the answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below. It will work

```
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```